# Form Submitting Via AJAX Despite Failing Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm new to Ajax and I wanted to use it with a contact form currently in use. The form is set up to run JS (fieldchk()) to validate the require fields and then sends an email to the appropriate party.

I have set up the Ajax correctly, in that the email is sent and a message is displayed on the same page:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return fieldchk();
    var url = $(this).attr('action');
    var formData = $(this).serialize();
        $.post(url, formData, function(response){
            $('#feedback_form').html("<p>Thanks for contacting us!</p>");
        });
});
```

**Edit**: now the form gets validated and if it's valid, it does not send the email. Validation works correctly now.

Here is my form code:

```
<form 
    name="feedback" 
    action="feedbackact.cfm?type=feedback" 
    method="post"  
    enctype="multipart/form-data"
>
```

This is the code I use to validate the form:

```
function fieldchk() {
    errmsg = '';
    if (document.feedback.name.value == ''){
        errmsg = errmsg + 'You must enter your name.\n';
    }

    ... all the fields get checked like this ...

    if (errmsg > ''){
        alert(errmsg);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are doing a `fieldchk()` on submit.  Meaning: you are submitting the form already.  You may want to do validation on `click` instead and if validation passes, then submit the form.

Comment: It looks like you have 2 things happening on submit. `fieldchk` and then also listening for the submit event via jQuery.

I would remove the `onsubmit` attribute from your form, and place that function call in your submit handler.

Then, once your validation passes - you make the ajax request.

Comment: @dragonslovetacos I've taken your advice and removed the onsubmit from my form. Now it validates the form correctly but once the form is valid, the Ajax never executes. I must be missing something here. I'll edit my original post with the updated code.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add some type of validation in your JavaScript function. I would modify the markup

```
<form 
    name="feedback" 
    action="feedbackact.cfm?type=feedback" 
    method="post"
    enctype="multipart/form-data"
>
```

You do not need the onsubmit because the event listener is already listening for the form name. I assume the feedbackact.cfm page is what is determining if the form is valid or not? If that's the case, you're probably going to need to pass the form values to the coldfusion.

**However** I would do this differently:

> HTML:

```
<form name='feedback'><!--inputs--></form>

JavaScript:
$('form[name="feedback"]').on('submit', function() {

    var formData = this.serializeArray();

    if ( fieldcheck( formData) ) { //verifying the form data is correct

        $.post(); //post data

        Coldfusion.navigate("feedbackact.cfm?type=feedback");

    }

    else { alert('not filled out correctly!') }

});
```

Comment: feedbackact.cfm takes the form information and sends it in an email. Validation occurs in a JS function on the same page as the form. Please see my edited post.

Comment: Then yes, you will need some JS validation, which should be called from within the form event handler; my previous code should work for you; just make sure fieldcheck returns a Boolean corresponding to the inputs. Once the form is submitted I would add Coldfusion.navigate( "feedbackact.cfm?type=feedback" ) which will send the email.